# Which low-level windows specific functions are used to implement std::thread/boost::thread/pthread in Windows?

Tags: c++, multithreading, pthreads, std

I want to know Which low-level windows specific functions are used to implement std::thread/boost::thread/pthread in Windows?
Thanks

Comment: Well, take a look at the implementation, it's open source.

Comment: Can you please elaborate it. I am too new to this field

Comment: You can download the `boost` source and inspect it? What do you want me to elaborate actually?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Why bother looking it yourself if some SO drone/s will look it up for you?

Comment: @MartinJames Well, sarcasm impact.

Answer (score 1):

The Win32 API, [CreateThread](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682453(v=vs.85).aspx), is the core function for starting a thread on Windows.

Most everything you need to know about thread APIs in Windows can be found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684841(v=vs.85).aspx).

Answer (score 1):

http://ci.boost.org/svn-trac/browser/trunk/libs/thread/src/win32/thread.cpp#L134

```
inline uintptr_t _beginthreadex(void* security, unsigned stack_size, unsigned (__stdcall* start_address)(void*),
                                      void* arglist, unsigned initflag, unsigned* thrdaddr)
{
    DWORD threadID;
    ThreadProxyData* data = new ThreadProxyData(start_address,arglist);
    HANDLE hthread=CreateThread(static_cast<LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES>(security),stack_size,ThreadProxy,
                                data,initflag,&threadID);
    if (hthread==0) {
      delete data;
      return 0;
    }
    *thrdaddr=threadID;
    return reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t const>(hthread);
}
```

Comment: I'm sure there are more subtle implementation details.